# Changing the program authority or authority provided

Tags: anchor

I was working on an anchor program that when I tested gave me the "Program failed to complete" error randomly. I read that generating a new wallet keypair with solana-keygen new would help but after doing so my program is unable to deploy and i get the error Program's authority Some(32BMsbefwV9PLzXenSoakzagGmdVqzxNctXYkqNiHKxT) does not match authority provided DFXxxFYktHT1Z7d1xWgq4WoMqniEfiNeTagU751xMLM. Does anyone know how I could proceed? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the old `program address`

You can fix this by deleting `target/` folder and running `cargo clean`. Then `anchor test` or `anchor build` and `anchor deploy` And keep in mind that you have to update the `declare_id` after deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the program was already deployed with a pre existing file system wallet. A program account stores something called an `Upgrade Authority` which maintains the publicKey of the wallet which has the authority to change the program. It usually is the file system wallet.

If you changed the `Keypair` of your file system wallet, you will not be able to change the program. You need to revert back to the old Keypair with which the program was deployed.